# Loop in an XML schema over elements with different names

Tags: c++, xml, qt, loops, schema

I have a xml-File that contains up to 19 Elements named DEPP1, DEPP2, ...,  up to DEPP19. ( There may be less than 19 elements though ) My XML-File would look like that:

```
<TD>
    <DEPP1>1</DEPP1>
    <DEPP2>2</DEPP2>
    ...
    <DEPP19>3</DEPP19>
</TD>
```

I also have a xml-schema that I use to read data from that XML-File. In this xsd-File I list all the possible elements that may occur. The schema looks like this:

```
 <xs:element name="TD">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="DEPP1" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP2" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP3" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP4" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP5" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP6" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP7" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP8" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP9" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP10" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP11" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP12" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP13" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP14" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP15" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP16" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP17" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>      
    <xs:element name="DEPP18" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="DEPP19" type="doubleField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>      
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Is there a nicer way to create the schema instead of repeating the same code for all Elements ( **which all have a different Name** ) using a loop ?

Thank you

itelly

Comment: just wondering, why `qt` tag? anything specific to `Qt`?

Comment: not really, forget about the qt tag

Comment: Does anybody have any idea ?